# Poem with A's and T's representing Ford model A's and T's in traffic

Tags: poetry, identification-request

I'm looking for an English poem, in fact I think it was at least two poems, that consisted of capital A's, representing the Ford Model A, moving as if in traffic, and another that had both A's and T's. The first, with only A's, was two vertical columns with only a few A's, representing the beginning of the automobile age when only a few model A's could be found on very simple roads. The second was a more complicated "road" (not just a vertical column) filled congestedly with both A's and T's.

Even though, if I'm recalling correctly, this has no words *per se*, it was in a collection of poetry I once encountered. I had thought it was by cummings or Sandberg, but I've been unable to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Richard Kostelanetz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Kostelanetz), ‘Tribute to Henry Ford’ (1968).

> the composition depicts the letters T and A, badges of the early model cars created by Ford, travelling various four-lane highways. In frame 1, the model Ts, introduced in 1908, carelessly ride the yet unmarked roads of turn-of-the-century America, roaring through the twenties. In frame 2, a far fewer number of model As, originated in 1928, come to a halt, forced to obey, one can infer, the newly instituted system of traffic lights. The funereal  orderliness with which they ride points to the reduced production and sobering economic reality of the times. In the third frame, a profusion of smaller, necessarily more maneuverable Ts and As, as automobile offspring, cruise superhighways and execute cloverleaf turns, manifesting the automania that came on the prosperity and technological prowess of post-war America. Thus the geometric artistry of the poem includes an intricate correspondence between images and American eras.
>
> <sub>Hildy Coleman (1995). ‘[Kostelanetz’s Tribute to Henry Ford](https://doi.org/10.1080/00144940.1995.9937248)’, *The Explicator* 53:2, pp. 123–125.</sub>

The poem appears on page 804 of [*The Treasury of American Poetry*](https://archive.org/details/isbn_9781568653679) (1978), edited by Nancy Sullivan. Here’s the first of its three parts:

[image: Tribute to Henry Ford 1, with letter Ts representing model Ts]